# Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History' in automation invoked Chrome browser

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Getting the following error and page is not getting loaded only with the automated script i.e. automation invoked Chrome browser.

When I am posting this question, I saw the different suggestion on existing posts about the same issue. But, I found all those are related to the issues with the application and not with the automation point of view. Page is getting loaded properly and working as expected in the manually opened Chrome browser.

```
Unhandled Navigation Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object
```

I think this issue might get resolved by adding any arguments or capabilities as it works well with the normal browser. Could any one confirm and provide the requirement argument or capability to add with the scripting.

Script already having the following arguments and capabilities added.

```
    optChrome.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[] { "enable-automation" });
    optChrome.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
    optChrome.addArguments("chrome.switches",
        "--disable-extensions --disable-extensions-file-access-check --disable-extensions-http-throttling");
```

Selenium Version: 4.11.0

Chrome Browser Installed: Version 116.0.5845.188 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Java: 1.8.0_291